# react native play mp3 from RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath

Tags: react-native

I have mp3 player working with `react-native-sound`

On my react native app, iOS, I have placed an mp3 file on the documents folder, I can check the file exists with RNFS

```
 /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/IDIDB/Documents/sample-3s.mp3
```

But when I try to play the file from my Documents folder it doesn't work or show any error...

```
const playMP3 = async (songPath) => {
        Sound.setCategory('Playback', true); // true = mixWithOthers

        console.log("playama:", songPath)

        const composedPath = `file:/${songPath}`

        console.log("---- composedPath:", composedPath)

        try {
            // const file = await RNFS.RNFS.read(songPath, 'base64');

            // const fileContent = await RNFS.RNFS.readFile(songPath, 'base64');
            // const tempFilePath = `file://${RNFS.RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}/temp.mp3`;
            // await RNFS.RNFS.writeFile(tempFilePath, fileContent, 'base64');
            // console.log('temp file path:', tempFilePath);
            // console.log("ahh:", songPath)

            RNFS.exists(songPath)
                .then((exists) => {
                    if (exists) {
                        console.log("EXISTS");


                        //
                        // const whoosh = new Sound(music1, (error) => {


                        const whoosh = new Sound(songPath, (error) => {
                            if (error) {
                                console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
                                return;
                            }
                            // loaded successfully
                            console.log('duration in seconds: ' + whoosh.getDuration() + 'number of channels: ' + whoosh.getNumberOfChannels());

                            // Play the sound with an onEnd callback
                            whoosh.play((success) => {
                                if (success) {
                                    console.log('successfully finished playing');
                                } else {
                                    console.log('playback failed due to audio decoding errors');
                                }
                            });
                        });

                        //


                    } else {
                        console.log("BLAH DOES NOT EXIST");
                    }
                }).catch(
                    (err) => { console.log("tubar: ", err) }
                );


        } catch (error) {
            console.log("error:", error)

        }

    }
```

I tried reading the file with RNFS as base64, but didn't work either...
how to play the mp3 from my local file system?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the answer after digging a lot!!

so the issue is the parameter missing after path...

```
    const whoosh = new Sound(songPath, "", (error) => {
```